# C# Guid.ToByteArray() equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

C# has a built-in function `ToByteArray()` please see below:

```
public byte[] ToByteArray()
{
    return new byte[16]
    {
        (byte)_a,
        (byte)(_a >> 8),
        (byte)(_a >> 16),
        (byte)(_a >> 24),
        (byte)_b,
        (byte)(_b >> 8),
        (byte)_c,
        (byte)(_c >> 8),
        _d,
        _e,
        _f,
        _g,
        _h,
        _i,
        _j,
        _k
    };
}
```

Is there any equivalent or an easy way to convert a SQL Server's `uniqueidentifier` to get the same byte array (as `varbinary`)?

Basically, I'm looking for equivalent of C#

```
byte[] arr = new Guid("FFFA9208-0391-4924-947F-C0556198D2FC").ToByteArray();
```

in SQL Server:

```
select MagicalFunction('FFFA9208-0391-4924-947F-C0556198D2FC') -- outputs varbinary
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your psuedocode is this:

```
select MagicalFunction('FFFA9208-0391-4924-947F-C0556198D2FC') -- outputs varbinary
```

Currently your GUID is actually a textual type, so you will first need to convert it to a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and then finally to a `VARBINARY`. You can do this like so:

```sql
SELECT CAST(CAST('FFFA9208-0391-4924-947F-C0556198D2FC' AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) AS VARBINARY(16))
```

Comment: ProgrammingLlama thank you! Casting to uniqueidentifier was a key!